# Flutter Riverpod ::type 'AutoDisposeChangeNotifierProvider' error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i keep getting this error from Riverpod

> type 'AutoDisposeChangeNotifierProvider' is not
> a subtype of type
> 'AutoDisposeChangeNotifierProviderFamily<ProviderPublicProfile,
> String>' of 'function result'

i am using it in correct way but i keep getting this error..

```
final profilePublicPage = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose
    .family<ProviderPublicProfile, String>((ref, userauthId) {
  return ProviderPublicProfile(read: ref.read, iduser: userauthId);
});
```

then using it like this

```
 final userPublicP = ref.watch(profilePublicPage(widget.id));
```

Comment: What you gave appears to be correct (and works in DartPad); there is probably an issue somewhere else.

Comment: i am just confused.. i just cant figure out what he his trying to tell me... @GregoryConrad

Comment: For us to figure out what is wrong, you will have to give a large code sample. For instance, where is the error coming from?